# Ухудшить качество изображения

Tags: php, изображения

Всем привет. 
   Сделал прикрепление изображения к комментарием, но сами фотографии оригинального размера и их вес может быть очень большим. Хочу уменьшить размер фотографии как в весе, так и в размере (примерно 400x400) на php. 
Кто и что может подсказать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php - quality в 0 и радуйтесь). И посмотрите там же слева функцию изменения размеров изображения.

Answer (score 0):

[imagecopyresampled](http://www.php.su/functions/?imagecopyresampled):

> копирует и изменяет размеры части изображения с пересэмплированием

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут инфа, которая вам нужна: [сложное масштабирование изображений в PHP](http://www.codenet.ru/webmast/php/Image-Resize-GD/)!